# Large number of polygons to plot on Folium map

Tags: polygon, geopandas, folium, image-segmentation

I've got a Geopandas Dataframe (polygon_df) that looks like the one below, these Polygons were created by a Yolo segmentation algorithm. Each line in the DataFrame represents a segmented group of solar panels.

```
    geometry
0   POLYGON ((648745.973 6764605.655, 648745.491 6...
1   POLYGON ((648709.785 6764626.587, 648709.304 6...
2   POLYGON ((648836.827 6764923.395, 648836.346 6...
3   POLYGON ((648283.746 6764392.271, 648283.426 6...
4   POLYGON ((648306.009 6764390.681, 648305.688 6...
5   POLYGON ((647965.957 6764363.920, 647962.427 6...
6   POLYGON ((648294.882 6764392.204, 648294.562 6...
7   POLYGON ((648211.211 6764461.638, 648210.409 6...
8   POLYGON ((648134.469 6764529.251, 648134.149 6...
9   POLYGON ((648158.487 6764524.252, 648158.005 6...
10  POLYGON ((648222.337 6764459.953, 648221.535 6...
11  POLYGON ((648146.079 6764527.563, 648145.277 6...
12  POLYGON ((647950.464 6764364.012, 647949.981 6...
```

The DataFrame has a little over 1 million Polygons (1062035). If it try to plot this on a Folium map it doesn't load or crashes. Is there a way for me to plot this on Folium through the usage of heatmaps which would group multiple solar panels together when they're close? I could introduce some sort of hierarchy on different zoom levels.

FYI: I already simplified the polygons with

> simple_df = gdf.simplify(4)